# How to read Tiff file or jpg file which having cursive writting?

Tags: java, ocr

I have developed a software which will convert `tiff` to `jpg` and then read `jpg` file, however this software only work when there is a simple writing on the `jpg` file (means simple English font) but I want to read cursive fonts so any one help me to get out of this. I have tried so much and yet I cannot find any kind of hint for this so please help..I don't understand which library I used? so help me for reading image which having cursive writing.

thanking you
vipul chauhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) on a cursive font document. If you mean handwriting, I'd give up immediately (a very difficult problem in general). If it IS a specific font that you posses (or at least you can create a database of pictures of each letter of that font) then you can try to use an existing OCR library that can be trained with a new font.

For example: [Tesseract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) or [OCRopus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/). Also try googling "java ocr train" or so.

Comment: thanks a lot and once again thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: I highly doubt if tesseract could be trained for cursive writing.